# Can intellisense pick up definitions without a definition file in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am still rather confused about how intellisense can find out definitions for my files. For example if I have a file called file1.ts:

```
///<reference path="../typescript/jquery.d.ts" />  
function x() {
    $.fn.y = function()
    {
    };
}
```

and another file file2.ts:

```
///<reference path="../typescript/jquery.d.ts" />  

$('a').y();
```

Can I just include a reference to file1.ts into my file2.ts for intellisense to work and show me that .y() can be added after $('a') or do you have to explicitly declare this in an interface or definition file and then add that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TypeScript walks the dependencies - so you only need to the jQuery definition in `file1.ts`:

This may be best explained in an example:

*file1.ts*

```
///<reference path="../typescript/jquery.d.ts" />

interface JQuery {
    y: () => void;
}

function x() {
    $.fn.y = function()
    {
    };
}
```

*file2.ts*

```
///<reference path="../typescript/file1.ts" />  

$('a').y();
```

Comment: Thanks. So I do absolutely need to declare the function inside my interface? I was hoping that typescript could just pick it up from the $.fn.y definition like would happen in C#.

Comment: Yes - without adding `y` to the jQuery interface, `file2.ts` will show an error. This is because it is the interface that is used when passing around the real jQuery object.